# Getting error of "Invalid column name '2017-09'.." while run sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

When i run below query, It gives me error `Invalid column name '2017-09'.`,
I tried some googling but still not getting the result for it, can anyone please look into this query and help me what can be the issue

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE when (SOC = "1" and MonthStart="2017-09") then 1 ELSE NULL END) as SOCCount_2017_09, 
COUNT(CASE when (Recert = "1" and MonthStart="2017-09") then 1 ELSE NULL END) as RecertCount_2017_09, 
COUNT(CASE when (Recert = "1" and MonthStart="2017-09") then 1 ELSE NULL END) as RecertPer1_2017_09, 
COUNT(CASE when (MonthStart="2017-09") then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEpisode_2017_09, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (FullHHRG > "0" and MonthStart="2017-09") then FullHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgFullHHRG_2017_09,
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (CMW > "0" and MonthStart="2017-09") then CMW ELSE NULL END),3) as AvgCMW_2017_09, 
COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = "1" and MonthEnd="2017-09") then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAs_2017_09, 
COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = "1" and MonthEnd="2017-09") then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAPer_2017_09, 
COUNT(CASE when ((MonthEnd="2017-09" and Status = "Closed") ) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEndEpisode_2017_09, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (SN_Ep = "1" and MonthEnd="2017-09") then SN_Visits ELSE NULL END),1) as SNVisitsSNEps_2017_09, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (THVisits > "0" and MonthEnd="2017-09") then THVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as THVisitsTHEps_2017_09, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = "Closed" and MonthEnd="2017-09") then TotVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTotVisits_2017_09, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = "Closed" and MonthEnd="2017-09") then SNVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgSNVisits_2017_09, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = "Closed" and MonthEnd="2017-09") then TotTherapy ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTHVisits_2017_09, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (NetHHRG > "0" and MonthEnd="2017-09") then NetHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgNetHHRG_2017_09, 
SUM(CASE when (Status = "Closed" and MonthEnd="2017-09") then TH_Ep ELSE NULL END) as TherapyPer_2017_09 
FROM tb_Episode WHERE CustID = "27" AND PayerType = "Ep" AND BranchID IN (241)
```

Comment: SQL-Server uses single quotes `'` for strings, not double quotes `"`.

Comment: @MatBailie Except maybe for SQLite...but watch out, because double quotes in SQLite are also for columns :-)

Comment: @MatBailie thank a lot, it works now

Comment: Be careful of quoting everything.  It ***appears*** that you're even quoting integers?  `THVisits > "0"`, that's a really bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `SQL-Server`, You have to use `Single Quotes(')` Instead of `Double Quotes(")` while using `Strings`.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE when (SOC = '1' and MonthStart='2017-09') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as SOCCount_2017_09, 
COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2017-09') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as RecertCount_2017_09, 
COUNT(CASE when (Recert = '1' and MonthStart='2017-09') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as RecertPer1_2017_09, 
COUNT(CASE when (MonthStart='2017-09') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEpisode_2017_09, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (FullHHRG > '0' and MonthStart='2017-09') then FullHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgFullHHRG_2017_09,
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (CMW > '0' and MonthStart='2017-09') then CMW ELSE NULL END),3) as AvgCMW_2017_09, 
COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2017-09') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAs_2017_09, 
COUNT(CASE when (LUPA = '1' and MonthEnd='2017-09') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LUPAPer_2017_09, 
COUNT(CASE when ((MonthEnd='2017-09' and Status = 'Closed') ) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as TotalEndEpisode_2017_09, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (SN_Ep = '1' and MonthEnd='2017-09') then SN_Visits ELSE NULL END),1) as SNVisitsSNEps_2017_09, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (THVisits > '0' and MonthEnd='2017-09') then THVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as THVisitsTHEps_2017_09, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-09') then TotVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTotVisits_2017_09, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-09') then SNVisits ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgSNVisits_2017_09, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-09') then TotTherapy ELSE NULL END),1) as AvgTHVisits_2017_09, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE when (NetHHRG > '0' and MonthEnd='2017-09') then NetHHRG ELSE NULL END),2) as AvgNetHHRG_2017_09, 
SUM(CASE when (Status = 'Closed' and MonthEnd='2017-09') then TH_Ep ELSE NULL END) as TherapyPer_2017_09 
FROM tb_Episode WHERE CustID = '27' AND PayerType = 'Ep' AND BranchID IN (241)
```